# try insert data to Excel file using OLEDB

Tags: c#, asp.net

it try to  insert data to Excel file using OLEDB, by this [Article](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-oledb-insert.htm) (4'th line)

But this line show incorrect

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwfhE.png

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

whay?

Comment: add reference to your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`

To add a reference in Visual C#

1. In **Solution Explorer**, right-click the project node and click **Add Reference**.
2. In the **Add Reference** dialog box, search for **Microsoft.Office.Interop.excel**
3. Select the components you want to reference, and then click OK.

This will resolve your issue.
[Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Comment: Arun Chandran C .
I dont fine Microsoft.Office.Interop.excel in Add Reference dialog box
http://i.stack.imgur.com/nwgw7.png

Comment: Arun Chandran C . I find

but now it fall in 

" MyConnection.Open();"

http://i.stack.imgur.com/PkDTk.png

Comment: Someone can tell my whay it fail in " MyConnection.Open();".


Screenshot of the problem: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PkDTk.png

Comment: check your exception in details or ask as  new question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection ;
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
                string sql = null;
                MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\\csharp.net-informations.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
                MyConnection.Open();
                myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
                sql = "Insert into [Sheet1$] (id,name) values('5','e')";
                myCommand.CommandText = sql;
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MyConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show (ex.ToString());
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add refrence to your project. Right click solution explorer and then add reference

Comment: What's the point of `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` if you never user it? Why don't you dispose your `OleDbConnection` or `OleDbCommand`?

Comment: 1. On the Project menu, click Add Reference.

2. On the COM tab, locate Microsoft Excel Object Library, and then click Select. In Visual Studio, locate Microsoft Excel 11.0 Object Library on the COM tab.

3.Click OK in the Add References dialog box to accept your selections. If you are prompted to generate wrappers for the libraries that you selected, click “Yes”.

Comment: I find but now it fail in " MyConnection.Open();". 
Screenshot of the problem: 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/PkDTk.png